# Making an html text field dynamic(Autocomplete jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is my Mysql query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_final, $final);
$query_Truck = "SELECT * FROM tbl_truck";
$Truck = mysql_query($query_Truck, $final) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Truck = mysql_fetch_assoc($Truck);
$totalRows_Truck = mysql_num_rows($Truck);
```

how can i get the data inside this to be in the jquery autocomplete with the id of the truck plate number being the one stored in the database and not the truck plate number itself?

Comment: use jquery ui autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: You are looking for the autocomplete functionality, you are better off googling for: `php jquery autocomplete mysql`

Comment: Select2 is a library for providing all sorts of useful select widgets. The AJAX version might be of particular interest: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play around with [jQuery's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). There are great examples on that site, and the [API is on this page.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Or, shameless plug, you can check out a random implementation of autocomplete on my own website, at [www.classbooklist.org](http://www.classbooklist.org)